# Dot-multiplying large dense matrices of different dtype (float x boolean)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, type-conversion, sparse-matrix

I am multiplying 2 matrices, `A.dot(B)`, where:

A = 1 x n matrix, dtype float

B = n x n matrix, dtype Boolean

I am performing this calculation for large n, and run out of memory very quickly (around n=14000 fails). A and B are dense.

It appears the reason is that numpy converts B to dtype float before performing the matrix multiplication, hence incurring a huge memory cost. In fact, %timeit suggests it spends more time converting B to float than performing the multiplication.

Is there a way round this? Emphasis here is on reducing the memory spike / float conversion, while still allowing common matrix functionality (matrix addition / multiplication).

Here's reproducible data for benchmarking solutions:

```
np.random.seed(999)
n = 30000
A = np.random.random(n)
B = np.where(np.random.random((n, n)) > 0.5, True, False)
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you convert `B` to float yourself prior to using `dot` i.e. does `A.dot(B.astype(float)` shows the same behavior?

Comment: The size of the matrix is below 1GB. If that’s already a problem, are you using 64 Bit Python? Regarding your question: float multiplication will ever only work with floats.  However as you essentially just add all floats where 1s are, can’t you use a row or column as Index to your vector & just sum?

Comment: Memory and calculation are very close for:

`A.dot(B.astype(float)` and `A.dot(B)`

If I convert B to float beforehand, calculation time drops significantly.

I'm aiming to perform this calculation for much larger n (at least n=30,000), so the memory improvement is critical, even on a machine with more memory.

Comment: can't you use sparse matrices?

Comment: MaxU, A and B are both dense. Sparse matrices may be prohibitively slow.

deets, Yes, I understand you can replicate the calculation by breaking down the matrix calculation and performing the summation manually. I was hoping that the highly optimised matrix algorithms in numpy could still be utilised.

Comment: That still leaves the question about the 64bits. And honestly: replacing multiplication + summation by just the latter is more efficient. Not sure if this can be exploited through indexing alone, but you could do it with a C-extension.

Comment: When arrays get very large, a few iterations over smaller blocks can be a time saver.  The savings in memory management time more than compensate for the extra time spent in iteration.

Comment: Well how sparse/how diagona/UT/LT are A and B? Which of the [seven storage schemes CSC/CSR/BSR/LIL/DOK/COO/DIA](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/storage_schemes.html) are they most amenable to, or their submatrices? Please give us some mocked-up example data for A and B. This is a really interesting question to tackle, but unless you give us reproducible data we can't effectively answer you. If B's is static and not arbitrary, you could try to get some optimal or reduced-dimensionality representation e.g try Cholesky decomposition. Really you're not giving enough information

Comment: @smci For this question, we can assume:

`n = 30000`

`A = np.random.random(n)`

`B = np.where(np.random.random((n, n)) > 0.5, True, False)`

A @ B is not possible on my machine, as numpy converts it to float to perform the matrix multiplication.

Comment: @hpaulj's suggestion is saying the same thing in a different way: find a more efficient sparse block representation of B's submatrices (manually if necessary), then perform the dot-product piecewise.

Comment: Aren't you just trying to sum different subsets of `A`?  You might try element multiplication followed row sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save space and time compressing the boolean array into a bitfield using `np.packbits` and then `np.bincount` on the rows to compute blocks of 8 scalar products simultaneously.

```
import numpy as np

def setup_data(M, N):
    return {'B': np.random.randint(0, 2, (M, N), dtype=bool),
            'A': np.random.random((M,))}

def f_vecmat_mult(A, B, decode=np.array(np.unravel_index(np.arange(256), 8*(2,)))):
    M, N = B.shape
    out = [(decode * np.bincount(row, A, minlength=256)).sum(axis=1) for row in np.packbits(B, axis=1).T]
    if N & 7:
        out[-1] = out[-1][:N & 7]
    return np.concatenate(out)

def f_direct(A, B):
    return A @ B

import types
from timeit import timeit

for M, N in [(99, 80), (999, 777), (9999, 7777), (30000, 30000)]:
    data = setup_data(M, N)
    ref = f_vecmat_mult(**data)
    print(f'M, N = {M}, {N}')
    for name, func in list(globals().items()):
        if not name.startswith('f_') or not isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
            continue
        try:
            assert np.allclose(ref, func(**data))
            print("{:16s}{:16.8f} ms".format(name[2:], timeit(
                'f(**data)', globals={'f':func, 'data':data}, number=100)*10))
        except:
            print("{:16s} apparently failed".format(name[2:]))
```

Sample output:

```
M, N = 99, 80
vecmat_mult           0.12248290 ms
direct                0.03647798 ms
M, N = 999, 777
vecmat_mult           1.67854790 ms
direct                5.68286091 ms
M, N = 9999, 7777
vecmat_mult          68.74523309 ms
direct              571.34140913 ms
M, N = 30000, 30000
vecmat_mult        1345.18991556 ms
direct           apparently failed
```

Comment: For some reason, I see identical performance for `A @ B` and `A @ B.view(np.int8)`. I'm using python 3.6.2 and numpy 1.13.1.

Comment: I'm on 3.6.0 and 1.13.3. No clue :( It seems pretty consistent on my end.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I've found something that is another 2-3 times faster on my machine. Could you have a look?

Comment: Your latest method is indeed much faster and I will accept it. One final query regarding generalisation. How could you generalise the below function for any n? [Some of the numpy functionality you use is beyond me, but I am planning to understand it better.]  
  
`def vecmat_mult(A, B):  


    DC = np.array(np.unravel_index(np.arange(256), 8*(2,)))  


    return np.concatenate([(DC * np.bincount(row, A)).sum(1) for row in np.packbits(B.ravel()).reshape(len(A), -1).T])`